# The lifetime of systemverilog method in the program block

Tags: system-verilog, lifetime

```
`define NUM 100
program test;
  function automatic int sum(int n);
    if(n <= 1) 
      return n;
    else 
      return n + sum(n-1);          
  endfunction
  
  initial begin
    $display("sum(%0d)=%d",`NUM, sum(`NUM)); 
    
  end

endprogram
```

Above is a piece of code that did a recursive exercise of the sum of incremental integers from 1 to `NUM`. The result is as expected when I ran it in vcs/xcelium/Questa on the EDA playground.

```
sum(100)=       5050
```

However, when I tried to make a modify on the lifetime of `function int sum(int n)`:

```
program test;
  function int sum(int n);
    if(n <= 1) 
      return n;
    else 
      return n + sum(n-1);          
  endfunction
  
  initial begin
    $display("sum(%0d)=%d",`NUM, sum(`NUM)); 
    
  end
  
endprogram
```

The results are quite interesting:

```
VCS            : sum(100)=        100
Cadence xcelium: sum(100)=        5050
Questa         : sum(100)=        5050
```

I went back to the IEEE1800-2017 to find out the default lifetime of methods in the program block but I didn't get the explicit description about that. Would someone help me to clarify this?

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/v3gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences you are seeing are not due to the lifetime of the sum method—it's the order of evaluation of function calls within the expression `n + sum(n-1)`, which is indeterminate. If you reverse the expression to `sum(n-1) + n`, all tools give the correct result for a function with a static lifetime.

BTW, I strongly [recommend that you never use program blocks](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2009/05/07/programblocks/) in SystemVerilog. Use modules instead.

Comment: Hi Dave,
Thanks for the answer. I would like to learn more about the evaluation of function calls within the expression. How does it make the tool confusing? 

You are right I was a Vera user. When I do some short example code, I used to use a program block. Good view from your link about the use of program block.